# Using Python to log into a tricky website

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I work in digital marketing as a data analyst. My department uses third parties to help bring in more customers. Each of these third parties have a website where they show how many customers they have brought into our company. Part of my job is collecting numbers from each website and putting them into a report which is a long and manual process. So far I've been successful in logging into some of our third party websites and extracting some data. However, there is one website I'm having some trouble logging into... **https://inspire.flg360.co.uk/SignIn.php**. I also need to redirect the session to another URL to scrape the data from.

I have written some code that has been successful in logging into a different website that I need information from.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

username = 'username'
password = 'password'
scrape_url = 'https://portal.mvfglobal.com/index.php/dashboard'

login_url = 'https://portal.mvfglobal.com/index.php/login/login'
login_info = {'login_name': username, 'login_pass': password}

#Start session.
session = requests.session()

#Login using your authentication information.
session.post(url=login_url, data=login_info)

#Request page you want to scrape.
url = session.get(url=scrape_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

However, when I try to log into **https://inspire.flg360.co.uk/SignIn.php** using the same methodology I encounter some problems.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

username = 'username'
password = 'password'
login_url = 'https://inspire.flg360.co.uk/SignIn.php'
login_info = {'strEmail': username, 'strPassword': password}

scrape_url = 'https://inspire.flg360.co.uk/AuthUser.php'

#Start session.
session = requests.session()
#Login using your authentication information.
session.post(url=login_url, data=login_info)
#Request page you want to scrape.
url = session.get(url=scrape_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

When I inspect the element of the page I noticed that the 302 response redirects to https://inspire.flg360.co.uk/AuthUser.php. However when I try to log into this using the code above I still get errors.

I'm completely stumped any ideas?

**Final Code Below________________________________________________________**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import hashlib

username = 'username'
password = 'password'
login_url = 'https://inspire.flg360.co.uk/AuthUser.php'
login_info = {"strForwardURL": "",
              "strEmail": username,
              "intRememberMe": 1,
              "strResponse": ""}

scrape_url = 'https://inspire.flg360.co.uk/ma/index.php'

# Start session.
session = requests.session()

# Get strResponse
strc = session.get(url=login_url)
strc = BeautifulSoup(strc.content, 'html.parser').findAll(attrs={"name": "strChallenge"})[0]['value']
strc_joined = strc + hashlib.md5(password.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
strresponse = hashlib.md5(strc_joined.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
login_info['strResponse'] = strresponse

#Login using your authentication information.
session.post(url=login_url, data=login_info)

# Request page you want to scrape.
url = session.get(url=scrape_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

Comment: apart from that though the page probably has a csrf_token which is the last required piece. You can find this if you inspect the page...

Comment: Interesting, I'll look on google for examples. Where on the inspect page is it located?

Comment: ah yours is a stringChallenge, I will update.

Comment: right click the page in your browser and the bottom option is "inspect" it will open up a bar in the right of the page and display the code used for page generation. Yours is under <div id="container middle"> == $0. They have data in the dropdowns for each menu. Most auth websites have some kind of handshake. This particular one is strChallenge, so you need to pass the data to the auth script.

Comment: Thanks d_kennetz that seemed to work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it looks like the actual POST request sent by the page at https://inspire.flg360.co.uk/SignIn.php  has a few more elements that are required. Namely, the POST data actually looks something like:

```
strForwardURL=&strEmail=abc%40123.com&intRememberMe=1&strResponse=fdb4c46c5d0eeab6133be193afc7897e
```

The fields are `strForwardURL`, `strEmail`, `intRememberMe`, and `strResponse`. Looking at the rest of the code on the page, when you click the submit button, it triggers this bit of javascript on the page:

```
    function fncSignIn() {

        var loginForm = document.getElementById("signinForm");

        if (loginForm.strEmail.value == "") {

            alert("Please enter your email address.");
            return false;

        }

        if (loginForm.strPassword.value == "") {

            alert("Please enter your password.");
            return false;

        }

        var submitForm = document.getElementById("submitForm");

        submitForm.strEmail.value = loginForm.strEmail.value;
        if (loginForm.intRememberMe.checked) submitForm.intRememberMe.value = 1;
        submitForm.strResponse.value = hex_md5(loginForm.strChallenge.value+hex_md5(loginForm.strPassword.value));

        submitForm.submit();

    }
```

Elsewhere on the page, you can find `strChallenge` string here:

```
<input type="hidden" name="strChallenge" value="1d989603e448a1a0559f08bdc83a15522fbc6c0404ca66acc4cdd7aafe4039359e2fb23b706d60a3">
```

(this value changes on reload, by the way)

Essentially, instead of the password in string form, it's asking for the md5 hex digest of the `strChallenge` string joined with the md5 hex digest of the password.

In python, it would be something like this:

```
import hashlib
password = "abcdefg12345"
strc = "1d989603e448a1a0559f08bdc83a15522fbc6c0404ca66acc4cdd7aafe4039359e2fb23b706d60a3"
strc_joined = strc + hashlib.md5(password.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
strresponse = hashlib.md5(strc_joined.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
print(strresponse)
```

And the output in this example would be 0d289f39067a25430d4818fe38046372

Make the postdata in your original request into:

`{"strForwardURL":"", "strEmail":"abc@123.com", "intRememberMe": 1, "strResponse": "0d289f39067a25430d4818fe38046372"}` and you should be able to log in. Every time you want to scrape a page that requires this particular login, you should be able to simply grab the `strChallenge` with BeautifulSoup4, calculate the proper `strResponse`, and log in.

Comment: Hi Jim I have updated my code. However, when print(soup) I'm still returning the html from the login page. I'm unsure if the login has worked I have updated my code in the original question. Maybe I'm missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind I had to change the login url to the Authuser URL