# Python Login to difficult website using requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am attempting to scrape data from https://www.fpl.com/my-account/login.html after logging in and re-directing to https://www.fpl.com/northwest/my-account/energy-dashboard. I have inspected the site and found the Username: `<input id="emailOrUserId" required="required" type="text">` and Password: `<input id="pwd" required="required" type="password">` HTML fields. On the re-direct URL I have also located the table I wish to scrape: `<table class="v-datatable v-table theme--light"`.

Using the requests package, and BeautifulSoup I have attempted the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload = {
    'emailOrUserId': "email@gmail.com",
    'pwd': "password"
}

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

loginUrl = "https://www.fpl.com/my-account/login.html"
dashboardUrl = "https://www.fpl.com/northwest/my-account/energy-dashboard"

with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post(loginUrl, data = payload, headers = headers)
    #r = session.get(loginUrl, headers = headers)
    #print(r.content)

    #Make request after login to other url within session
    request = session.get(dashboardUrl)
    print(request.text)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "lxml")
    table = soup.find("table", class_ = "v-datatable v-table theme--light")
    print(table)
```

This code can't seem to find the table, and always returns "None". Printing out the results from the first `session.post()` call indicates that the login fails. I assume I am missing something important with the post message formatting. [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54829882/using-python-to-log-into-a-tricky-website) gives some fantastic insight. I just need a little more help on the technical details of my specific use case.

I don't believe a CSRF Token is being used, but potentially something else as a simple security measure.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you login to that website (https://www.fpl.com/my-account/login.html) with the Chrome developer tools (or equivalent) running, you'll see that logging in is not a normal HTTP POST from the `<form>` element, but is actually triggered by the javascript.

When I do this, I see that a GET is triggered to https://www.fpl.com/cs/customer/v1/registration/loginAndUseMigration?migrationToggle=Y

This GET request contains the following HTTP header:
`Authorization: Basic Zm9vYmFyOmJheg==`

This is the standard "basic authentication" mechanism which you can use from `requests` as described here:
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/

Since I don't have a real account on this website, I can't actually follow the login flow all the way through, but you'll probably have to iteratively work your way through it starting from this point and using developer tools to see how tokens are managed.

As a shot in the dark, you might try a GET to your final desired page with the basic auth set in `requests` to see if that's sufficient for login, as in:

```
basic = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass')
requests.get('https://www.fpl.com/northwest/my-account/energy-dashboard', auth=basic)
```

However, you might find this is not sufficient and you have to start with `loginAndUseMigration`.

Also, you might also find that your final page requires javascript to render, in which case `requests` alone is not sufficient to scrape it.

Comment: I wrote it myself. No AI.